# Algorithmic equivalence

Tags: algorithm, function, complexity-theory

I came across this problem while studying algorithms in Java, where I am asked

to chose what `4 in the power of n` is equal to. Though I cant find a reference or a resource

to direct me towards the right solution.

[image: The function 4 in the power of n is equal to]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so f(n) = 4^n grows faster asymptotically speaking than all of these except n^n. Exponential functions with a constant base grow faster than logarithms or any polynomial (constant exponent) expression. 4^n grows more slowly than n^n and so 4^n = O(n^n) is true generally. Proving this is fairly trivial for the case n > 4.